# How can I run some code when a ajax call is complete in jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-effects

I have a div that contains some content. I want this div to be able to slide up and download some new content. When the content has been loaded via ajax, I want the div to slide down again and show the new content. I know how to handle each piece separately, but I do not know how to do them all at once. This is what I have:

```
$(element).slideUp('fast'); // slide up
$(element).slideDown('fast'); // slide down 
$(element).ajax(url); // download the text
```

Comment: Look at the [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): it is helpful in this scenario.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) I **strongly** recommend reading the jQuery ajax API docs.

Comment: There's one thing called "callback" in the documentation. Read it up.

Comment: Actually the callback function is called `success` in the `$.ajax` documentation, but it's recommended to bind a `.done()` handler to the jqXHR object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the slideUp's callback and the success handler for your ajax as well. Your code would look something like this:

```
$(element).slideUp('fast', function() {
    $.get(url, data, function (result) {
        $(element).html(result);
        $(element).slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax(url).done(function (response) {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: `.success` is deprecated on jQuery 1.8 in favor of [`.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

Comment: thanks a lot you are realy helpfull

Comment: +1, worse than this are the deprecated shorthand form selectors, but we'll live (and include compat plugins when needed). `=]`